# ChrQ definition

Tags: chromosome-capture

What is ChrQ?

I assume it then means chromosme Q or something like that yet when I google for it I get very weird answers, but as I saw that a couple times when looking on freebayes pipelines manuals I wanted to be sure.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include an example (or a few) of where you've seen this. It's almost certainly just a place holder, as Devon suggests, but we could give a more definitive answer if you could link us to the places you've seen this used.

Answer (score 1):

*Answer from @devon-ryan and @terdon, converted from comments:*

Are you sure it's not just a made up chromosome name that's useful in examples since people won't blindly copy/paste the command and have it work?

It's almost certainly just a place holder, as Devon suggests, but we could give a more definitive answer if you could link us to the places you've seen this used. If you only see it in relation to freebayes then yes the author is using it as “foo”.

*[please update / edit to improve this answer if you can]*